# ggplot, add grid lines between bars groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

When using dodged bars in a ggplot with discrete x axis, they are centered around the x ticks.
As a consequence, also the vertical grid lines pass along the tick in the middle of the group of bars.

[image]

I would like instead to have grid lines **between** the groups of bars. This is especially useful in cases like the one shown before, in which bars are sparse and is not immediate which group each bar belongs to.

Here's the code (without ordering of the x, which is not related and long to write):

```
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)

structure(list(Reparto = c("Oncologia medica", "Centro trapianti", 
"Chirurgia epatobiliare", "Dh oncologico", "Radioterapia", "Chirurgia", 
"Chirurgia oncologica", "Gastroenterologia", "Radiologia", "Oncologia medica", 
"Centro trapianti", "Chirurgia epatobiliare", "Dh oncologico", 
"Radioterapia", "Chirurgia", "Chirurgia oncologica", "Gastroenterologia", 
"Radiologia", "Oncologia medica", "Centro trapianti", "Chirurgia epatobiliare", 
"Dh oncologico", "Radioterapia", "Chirurgia", "Chirurgia oncologica", 
"Gastroenterologia", "Radiologia", "Oncologia medica", "Centro trapianti", 
"Chirurgia epatobiliare", "Dh oncologico", "Radioterapia", "Chirurgia", 
"Chirurgia oncologica", "Gastroenterologia", "Radiologia"), Fascia.oraria = c("00:00 - 3:00", 
"00:00 - 3:00", "00:00 - 3:00", "00:00 - 3:00", "00:00 - 3:00", 
"00:00 - 3:00", "00:00 - 3:00", "00:00 - 3:00", "00:00 - 3:00", 
"3:00 - 13:00", "3:00 - 13:00", "3:00 - 13:00", "3:00 - 13:00", 
"3:00 - 13:00", "3:00 - 13:00", "3:00 - 13:00", "3:00 - 13:00", 
"3:00 - 13:00", "13:00 - 24:00", "13:00 - 24:00", "13:00 - 24:00", 
"13:00 - 24:00", "13:00 - 24:00", "13:00 - 24:00", "13:00 - 24:00", 
"13:00 - 24:00", "13:00 - 24:00", "Orario sconosciuto", "Orario sconosciuto", 
"Orario sconosciuto", "Orario sconosciuto", "Orario sconosciuto", 
"Orario sconosciuto", "Orario sconosciuto", "Orario sconosciuto", 
"Orario sconosciuto"), Eventi = c(19.7, 2.19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 4.6, 1.32, 0.66, 0, 0.66, 0, 0, 0.66, 0, 7.77, 0, 1.2, 
1.2, 0, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -36L)) %>%
ggplot(aes(str_first_up(Reparto), Eventi)) +
        geom_col(aes(fill = Fascia.oraria), position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'total')) +
        theme(
            axis.text.x  = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
            panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(color = 'gray')
            ) +
        labs(x = NULL, y = 'N. eventi x 100 gg', fill = 'Fascia oraria')
```

Comment: please share your code and data (or subset) so people can help provide answers

Comment: Maybe turning off major grid and turning on minor grid would make this happen?

Comment: If you change your width and alpha arguments in your geom, you should be able to overlap the bars. I would get rid of the grid lines completely, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: Honestly, when I had this issue I just switched themes. I recommend theme_minimal(), but what you really ought to do is see if any of the possible themes are more appealing to you.

Comment: I am already using my own theme (I forgot to mention). I just don't how (or if it is possible) to nudge the gridlines in order to make them fall between the bar groups and not in the middle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually set the lines like this:

```
p +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) + # remove grid lines
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(0.5, length(df$Reparto), by = 1), color="gray", size=.5, alpha=.5) # set vertical lines between x groups
```

where `p` is your original plot, and `df` is your data.frame.

[image]

Obs: To produce this picture, I removed the `str_first_up()` from your code since it's not from `dplyr` or `ggplot` packages (current versions). Also, I added `theme_bw()` before your theme settings.

Comment: Ugh.  I can see how this works, but it just seems like there should be a better solution using the panel grid for this.

Comment: Ugh.  After looking around awhile, this does seem to be the way to go.  Upvoted+1.